# how to enable java in Browser on Centos 6.5

Tags: linux, centos, java, rpm

i already install Java (jdk 6u45 and jre 6u45) in a Centos 6.5 Server, but i don't know why in my browser appears to enable java plugin, these are steps to install java in my machine:

```
rpm -ivh jdk-6u45-linux-i586.rpm
rpm -Uvh jdk-6u45-linux-i586.rpm

rpm -ivh jre-6u45-linux-i586.rpm
rpm -Uvh jre-6u45-linux-i586.rpm
```

Can somebody help me guys with that issue? Thank you very much!
By the way, i'm trying to enable in Chrome and Mozilla Firefox...

Comment: Why are you using CentOS server as a desktop OS to begin with...?

Comment: look, i just want to do some tests, as a client machine, no matter what distro i am using it, but i have to enable java in a browser!

Comment: i already search it, but i haven't found it yet, but its ok i think is  better to keep it searching instead of waiting a simple answer or help....

Answer (score 1):

You need to install the web-plugin, on top of java:

```
yum install icedtea-web
```

This took me about 25 second of googling...

Comment: now this post is #1 on google

Comment: Still the OP never came back. It seems that his account is disabled

Comment: Also, following the steps the OP does and then this, Java is NOT enabled in Chrome

Comment: Centos is not shipped with centos. If the OP wants to know about chrome's centos he needs to be explicit about it