# Using Java in Chrome on Centos 7

Tags: linux, google-chrome, centos, java

I have installed java on my computer running CentOS 7. I've tried `yum install java` downloading the proper rpm for my bitness from [java.com/en/download](https://www.java.com/en/download/manual.jsp?locale=en). I've also done as suggested in this [how to enable java in Browser on Centos 6.5](https://superuser.com/questions/751133/how-to-enable-java-in-browser-on-centos-6-5) and installed `icedtea-web`

What am I missing to get Java working in Chrome?

Comment: take a look here http://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/JavaRuntimeEnvironment
I assume you need to do the following:

Create links in the Mozilla Plugins directory so Java will work in supported browsers such as Firefox.

# cd /usr/lib/mozilla/plugins/
# ln -fs /usr/java/latest/lib/i386/libnpjp2.so


Look here for chrome path https://www.centos.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=6019

Answer (score 0):

From [FAQ Java-Chrome](http://www.java.com/en/download/faq/chrome.xml):

**Chrome and Linux**

Starting with Chrome version 35, NPAPI (Netscape Plug-in API) support was removed for the Linux platform. For more information, see [Chrome and NPAPI](http://blog.chromium.org/2013/09/saying-goodbye-to-our-old-friend-npapi.html) (blog.chromium.org).

Firefox is the recommended browser for Java on Linux.